Excel workbook created with VSTO does not execute buttons after save
So I did the following steps:

Prepared an Excel VSTO Add-in, where the add-in creates two excel sheets and positions several buttons on those two sheets. Each button can have trivial or non-trivial action assigend. For example, button1 will simply increase the font size, while button2 will use the VSTO c# code to initialize several classes, process the data and print output to sheet. It all works when running excel from the Visual Studio.
I then save the woorkbook (tried also saving as "with macro enabled").
Close excel. Close Visual Studio.
Reopen workbook with Excel.
Click on any button and nothing happens -> like there is no functionality attached to the buttons.

Is this known limitation or am I doing something wrong?
My goal is to use VSTO Add-in to create a functional sheet (add formatting, add buttons,...) that later anybody could open without actually installing the Add-in. I am now doubting that is even possible.

The actions for the buttons are part of the add-in, not part of the sheet.
When you add a button, that is changing the sheet itself. When you add an event handler to the button, that is calling code in the add-in, not the sheet.
You need the add-in to look for the buttons when you open the document, and then attach the event handlers at that point.

OK, so without the add-in, other users won't be able to use the buttons. Right?
Is there a different way to create a workbook with all the events/buttons, that does not require the user to install anything? Except for the writing of the VBA Marco code?

Yes, but then you will need your buttons to fire VBA macro code and not your C# VSTO code. If you want to use VSTO, perhaps you want to use document level customizations https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2017/vsto/programming-document-level-customizations?view=vs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019-archive#combine-vba-and-document-level-customizations . If you are not set on a technology, then I would suggest considering office.js.

I am certainly not limited to VSTO. I don't really care what I use. All I want is to (let that be using python, C++, C#, ...) create a workbook with two sheets and several Form buttons (or ActiveX buttons, as long as they work) on those sheets. I would prefer it if user didn't have to install anything but I am willing to accept a simple installation as well, e.g. VSTO installation. You seem to know a lot about this topic. May I ask what would you recommend? What I don't want is to use the Excel's developer tab and write VBA Macro there - I find that horrible.

Anyway, I'm accepting your answer because it does answer my original problem.

I would certainly recommend office.js over VSTO if it supports the interactive features you want. You could also look into using C# and the OpenXML SDK for adding the buttons in the first place. This allows you to edit the document directly instead of interacting with an instance of Excel.
